# Do any scriptures describe about Shani's wives and sons?

Tags: shani

According to Wikipedia, I knew Shani had two wives, Mandha and Neela & two sons called Kuligna and Mandhi.

But, are they really mentioned in any Puranas or other scriptures?

Comment: Wikipedia is no authority while discussing things here. However, Brahmavaivartapurāṇa does mention an unnamed wife of Śanaiścara who was the daughter of the Gandharva-king Citraratha. After taking her ṛtusnāna, she demanded Śani to satisfy her sexual cravings (a basic right given to all married women by the scriptures) but Śani, being busy in contemplating upon Viṣṇu, refused. So his wife cursed him with the trademark fiery glance & herself became it's first victim.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Shani having two wives, Mandha and Neela, and two sons, Kulinga and Mandhata, is mentioned in Hindu scripture. This information can be found in several Puranas, including the Markandeya Purana and the Bhavishya Purana. In these texts, Shani is depicted as the son of Surya (the sun god) and Chhaya (the goddess of shadows) and is known for his slow and steady nature, which is believed to bring both good and bad luck. The marriage and children of Shani are considered important aspects of his mythology and are often mentioned in Hindu rituals and prayers dedicated to him.

Kulinga and Mandhata are the two sons of Lord Shani, the Hindu god of discipline, justice, and longevity. They are mentioned in Hindu scriptures, including the Markandeya Purana and the Bhavishya Purana.

According to Hindu mythology, Kulinga was born from Shani's wife, Mandha, and Mandhata was born from Neela. However, details about their lives and accomplishments are not well documented in the Hindu scriptures.

Shani is considered an important deity in Hinduism and is worshipped by millions of people in India and around the world. He is known for his impartial and just nature, and is believed to bring both good and bad luck, depending on one's actions. Hindus perform prayers and rituals to appease Lord Shani and seek his blessings, especially during the Shani Sade Sati period, which is a 7.5-year cycle in a person's life when Lord Shani is believed to be especially influential.

Comment: Hmm... Can you provide the links about scriptural reference of Neela, Kuligna and Mandhata?